# how to run get requests?

Tags: https

There use to be something called GET or HTTP so you could run get requests to a page, or download pages.

This would be helpful for testing servers and doing stuff from CLi instead of using a browser.

Is there any binary for this mean?

Comment: Read `man wget`.

Comment: Also `curl` - `man curl`

Comment: and install postman :)

Comment: @Rinzwind tried that one, it's great, but for simple things it'd be good to use something simpler, to keep my RAM chill. Thanks all of you. I got confused and installed httptty or random bins but that was bad idea i guess